# state server session - cross appDomain?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

When using a State server for session, are sessions still appDomain specific?  So for example, I have two different IIS applications(virtual directories) on a web server, and they both point to one state server for session.  The session guid from the cookie will be the same across requests from both applications, so will the same session be accessible across both of these applications?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @ntziolis mentioned in his answer, and @Aristos mentioned in his comment, the session is based on a combination of the application name and the session cookie. You can get it to work (as I just did) if the application name is the same and the session cookie value is the same.

To get the application name to be the same, I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290992/asp-net-sharing-session-state-between-different-net-versions-using-state-server) from SO that uses reflection:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string applicationName = "MySiteName";

    // Change the Application Name in runtime.
    FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
    FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, applicationName);
}
```

I added that to both Global.asax files (of each of my sites).

To get the session cookie to be the same, the cookie cannot be invalid due to the path or the domain. If you have two virtual directories under the same site, you are fine on the cookie's path & domain issue.

Unless you added explicit code to your web.config file, the session cookie's name and machine key would also be the same by default. If not, you would need to make sure your `<machineKey>` is explicitly set and the same between the two applications, and the value for `cookieName` in `<sessionState>` is explicitly set and the same between the two applications:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="77D2713C3E6C46160F278B7F4787A341A8E9010C3C228F8E9522685050F5204ECA0F2BA2169C4F29C1ADD8C3B99E7143A21272A59373BFBEF21C6677D0FF293C" decryptionKey="286F0EA94D5DA2E697C8C148934EF885A6513AD91C044EDFE7DC45027653B830" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <sessionState cookieName="mySessionCookie" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That worked for me - I was able to spin up a proof-of-concept web site for this.

Comment: Note that hacking `AppDomainAppId` like this confuses IIS, preventing it from being able to automatically recycle the app when you change things like uploading a new DLL. You'll need to recycle the app pool manually instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is **not the appDomain but the application name** (in the web.config). As long as the application name is the same you should be able to share session state.

For different application names check **[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2007/01/25/sharing-asp-net-session-state-across-applications.aspx)**.

Comment: I think you make an error - even if you have the same application name, that you mix up everything, then the program when get from one app to the other ask for the session cookie that is not found on the second one and create again a new session for the same user under the same database (if they have the same app name). Bad practice to have the same application name for different applications.

Comment: @Aristos - You are right, but I assumed of course that the session cookie would also have been unified, otherwise it doesn't make sense to unify session storage. And yes this is not pretty, but its the only way I know of without having to change the underlying providers. If this has changed please let us know.

Comment: ok I accept your argument. Now there is one think that I do not know (and I wish to learn), how you can unified the cookie across 2 different web site.

Comment: The link you give is concerning SQLServer session mode, not StateServer session mode - OP is asking about state server session. How do you set application name in StateServer session mode?